# What does it mean by "Followup: MachineOwner"?

Tags: windows, debugging, windbg, crash-dumps

The following message is copied from WinDBG's output window:

```
Use !analyze -v to get detailed debugging information.

BugCheck 24, {1904fb, 8f9ec9f8, 8f9ec5d0, 87c4fccc}

Probably caused by : Ntfs.sys ( Ntfs!NtfsCommonRead+6f4 )

Followup: MachineOwner
```

Please note the last line: **"Followup: MachineOwner"**

What does it mean?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Followup output is the attempt by the `!analyze` command to triage the exception to identify who owns the fault, sometimes it could be a driver, hardware, application etc..

There is a default entry in the triage.ini file that `!analyze` (and also `!owner` command) uses when it cannot find a match:

> default=MachineOwner

This file is located in a folder called *triage* on my machine it is in

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Debuggers\x64\triage

It is something you can ignore in your case, there is more [information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff558788%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) about how the analysis works and how to [edit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff560201%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) the *triage.ini* file for your specific use case.